# kworker hogging CPU after getting additional SSD - high acpi interrupts on gpe11, masking or disabling causes system freeze

Tags: kernel, performance, cpu, acpi

Mine is a 7 year old Dell Inspiron 3542 (Intel i5), have been running Linux for about 5 years now.

Recently I got an additional SSD fitted in the HDD slot and moved the HDD into the place of DVD Drive using a caddy. Then I did a fresh install of Xubuntu 20.04 onto the SSD. I noticed high CPU usage on CPU 0 (~75%) even when nothing much is running on the PC. top command shows me a kworker process hogging CPU:

```
   184 root      20   0       0      0      0 I  75.7   0.0  17:31.07 kworker/0:2-kacpid
```

The usual solution with other similar problems posted here is to figure out which GPE is causing too many interrupts and disable that. Output of `grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts` shows the below lines with high values:

```
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe11:11640215  EN STS enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci:11640301
```

Disabling or masking gpe11 with `echo mask > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe11` causes the system to freeze (monitor, keyboard and mouse become unresponsive, if any sound was playing the sound starts looping like a DJ did something)

Disabling or masking sci resets the gpe11 and sci interrupts to zero, but they start increasing again. No effect on cpu usage, which is still high

Other experiments and observations:

- The usual kernel parameter changes such as `acpi=off` and `acpi_mask_gpe=0x11` caused a blank screen at boot
- The problem persists on OS booted from Live USB too
- The problem persists on Xubuntu 18.04, and Arch Linux latest release Live USB too
- Output of `cat /proc/interrupts` is below (truncated till acpi):

  ```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:          6          0          0          0   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  1:       9379          0          0          0   IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042
  8:          0          1          0          0   IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
  9:          0   21362967          0          0   IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
  ```
- Relevant Output of `echo l > /proc/sysrq-trigger` onto dmesg is below

  ```
  [ 2174.058304] CPU: 0 PID: 184 Comm: kworker/0:2 Not tainted 5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu
  [ 2174.058305] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 3542/0926J6, BIOS A03 05/27/2014
  [ 2174.058307] Workqueue: kacpid acpi_os_execute_deferred
  [ 2174.058309] RIP: 0010:acpi_ns_search_one_scope+0x16a/0x208
  [ 2174.058310] Code: 49 89 1f 45 31 c0 b9 10 00 00 00 bf 74 00 00 00 48 c7 c2 b0 e8 ca a0 48 c7 c6 90 e8 ca a0 e8 f3 d9 00 00 31 c0 e9 8f 00 00 00 <48> 8b 5b 20 e9 4c ff ff ff f6 05 7d dc 19 01 04 74 55 f6 05 c3 34
  [ 2174.058312] RSP: 0018:ffffb5850051fb80 EFLAGS: 00000212
  [ 2174.058313] RAX: 0000000037314547 RBX: ffff8947808f57b0 RCX: 0000000000000010
  [ 2174.058314] RDX: ffffffffa0cae8b0 RSI: ffffffffa0cae890 RDI: 0000000000000042
  [ 2174.058315] RBP: ffffb5850051fbb0 R08: 0000000000000005 R09: 0000000000000003
  [ 2174.058317] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffffffa1a7e880
  [ 2174.058318] R13: ffff8947801d1b40 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffb5850051fc60
  [ 2174.058319] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8947aba00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
  [ 2174.058320] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
  [ 2174.058321] CR2: 00007f4c9b5e4d9c CR3: 0000000069074001 CR4: 00000000001706f0
  [ 2174.058322] Call Trace:
  [ 2174.058323]  acpi_ns_search_and_enter+0x347/0x4ca
  [ 2174.058325]  acpi_ns_lookup+0x63e/0x866
  [ 2174.058326]  acpi_ps_get_next_namepath+0xbc/0x35a
  [ 2174.058327]  acpi_ps_get_next_arg+0x69d/0x79a
  [ 2174.058328]  ? acpi_ut_trace_ptr+0x2b/0x71
  [ 2174.058329]  acpi_ps_parse_loop+0x4be/0x924
  [ 2174.058330]  acpi_ps_parse_aml+0x1af/0x550
  [ 2174.058331]  acpi_ps_execute_method+0x208/0x2ca
  [ 2174.058332]  acpi_ns_evaluate+0x34e/0x4f0
  [ 2174.058333]  acpi_ev_asynch_execute_gpe_method+0xc0/0x15e
  [ 2174.058334]  acpi_os_execute_deferred+0x1a/0x30
  [ 2174.058335]  process_one_work+0x220/0x3c0
  [ 2174.058336]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x3f0
  [ 2174.058337]  kthread+0x114/0x150
  [ 2174.058338]  ? process_one_work+0x3c0/0x3c0
  [ 2174.058339]  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
  [ 2174.058340]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
  ```
- Output of `sudo dmidecode` for `0x0011` is below. Not sure if `0x0011` corresponds to `gpe11`. If that's not how the GPE numbering works, I can provide full output.

  ```
  Handle 0x0011, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
  On Board Device Information
      Type: Video
      Status: Enabled
      Description: Mobile Intel HD Graphics
  ```
- Tried removing HDD Caddy, system won't boot at all (stuck at kernel panic) - from both SSD and Live USB
- Tried flipping the switch on Caddy, same result as removing the caddy
- Tried doing BIOS Update but the update failed. That is a separate issue because Dell provides only EXE files for updating

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself :)

Somehow got the system to boot with the HDD removed. It happened when I was trying random things, the latest being booting a live USB of Void Linux. The CPU usage was back to near zero

After that I tried flipping the switch on the caddy and now the system booted with CPU usage near zero.

Comment: Too old? I'm having issues with gpe61 and sci going non-stop and weirdness with plugging/unplugging ac adapter(it is out of phase: unplugging looks like plugging in to system). Am I correctly interpreting your solution? You flipped a HW switch and now have normal operation? If so, sounds like you had a similar out-of-phase issue. HDD was in but switch reported it as out. One toggle brought it back and things were fine? How can I map my gpe?